# Is there a api or way to hook into SSRS with a MVC application

Tags: javascript, api, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I know this is a general question, but not sure if I am googling it incorrectly, or if what I am wondering isnot possible. Our compny already has a report server running with many SQL reports on it. I am wanting to see if I can make a front end using MVC and JS to coomunicate with the report server and allow a user to run reportts using a web application MVC interface. Does SSRS allow this type of functionality, or would it be as lame as just calling the URL of each report,and then designing it how ever i would like in my MVC project?  So if i add a new report to the report server, i would then have to update the MVC front end project the end users in the company use, to now have the new report. I am hoping there is a way to sort of call the SSRS services, and return reports so i can then use templates or something along those lines in my MVC web app. That way it is dynamically getting the reports from the report server as we build or change it.

So once again, super sorry this is a general question and i have searched google n this from SSRS with MVC to many other combos, but cannot seem to find what i am looking for. I guess in short, does SSRS have a API interface i can use for a MVC front end application to make it nicer, and better public facing for those who will use the report services?

Thanks in advance, and just hoping for some direction on where i can then myself get the answer. No holding hand wishing here. Thanks!

Comment: Googling "asp.net mvc ssrs report viewer" seems to have some good results.  What about these tutorials didn't work for you?

Comment: I once implemented this with an iframe that has a url to the report viewer and various parameters in the query string. It can be achieved, but you'll have to find out how to handle security concerns

Comment: I googled that. I guss I am having trouble explaining what i am trying to acomplish. I am trying to make a MVC front end so in a view, i can for example LIst All Reports" available on the service in a group folder, lets say accounting. Then use the MVC app to drive it. Form what I saw, i can reference the URL to the report from the MVC app, but then it just displays it in a iframe. Is there no other way to get more out of being able to customize how users interact running the reports, hence why i am wanting to make my own front end in MVC. For now, i guess i can just use those results.

Comment: I am hoping or wishing there was a api such as MCV method. {report folder group}/{reportName} and then send the params to the service, and get the results but in a kendo grid. So get the xml or json results. Something along those line,s but from what i see is wishful thinking. The reason for this is our IT manager wants a better UI to allow users to run reports and build them dynamically, so instead of developing a entirely new system, i was hoping i could hook into the already made SSRS system we have. But make it "prettier" and extendable to customize in MVC. Just doing what im asked. :)

Comment: I know this question was made long time ago, but I came here looking for answers because I want to achieve the same result than you. Did you find any solution here or at least confirm that it is not possible to do what you wanned? If so please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing this, depending on how you want to build your application.

1. SSRS has a [built-in SOAP API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/report-server-web-service#user-requirements-for-web-service-development). You can easily use a SOAP client package to make requests to the web service, and get back formatted data from your reports.  This is the way to do it if you actually want to display the data as HTML.
2. There are several ways to do this by generating a PDF (I used this approach in building my application).  This [blog article](http://blog.chrisbriggsy.com/How-to-Integrate-SSRS-and-WebAPI/) outlines how to build your own `.net` endpoint which returns a PDF.  You could then call thus custom API from your MVC.  You can also just use a query string, depending on the level of customization which is needed.

Obviously I don't know a lot about your particular usecase, but my tendency would be to suggest building a separate API outside of SSRS for you to access. This would add to the security of your application (as you can limit the types of reports generated per user) and limit the overhead of the application in having to interact with SSRS.

Comment: @Casey reading your comment- use the SOAP API to list the available reports, and then use the Query String API to get the PDFs.

Comment: Awesome, thats what i was wondering. I know some of the results mentioned by the prior comments and user that i too came across stated some things about SOAP request and results, but i kept seeing to display the url's in a iframe or something. SO this lets me know worth looking into, and can accomplish what it is my IT manager is requesting as a end game plan. -Thanks-

Comment: Thanks. That is the next step. How to get the list of reports, then displaying them. Thanks for mentioning that.